# cmdlet design: parameter pass in: pipeline or inline parameter?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

It is not a programming question but instead more of a designing question.

Assuming data is stored in json.

For example, `Get-Person "John" | Get-Employer` or `Get-Employer -Person "John"`

Both way looks to return John's employer, the former one uses pipeline and later one uses inline parameter. I am sometimes confused: what is the advantage and disadvantage of each? When you guys are designing, what is your preference to use each of them?

For me, the only reason I come up with using the pipeline is that it saves us using variables if the value of the parameter needs to be evaluated.

Anyone has any thoughts on this question too?

Comment: As said, good function design can handle both so that the user itself can choose what he/she likes. Just as a FYI though, your examples are not equal. In the first you pass an object(what I would imagine is a "person" object for the person "john"), while the second only takes his name. `"John" | Get-Employer` would be the correct alternative

Comment: I agree with @Graimer. As a consumer of cmdlets, I want it both ways - let me pass in a single/collection of values when needed or pipe in a collection (or single value) from another source. Each method will come in useful in various situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason you need to pick one or the other.  With proper parameter attributes and function design (use begin/process/end blocks) you can allow both options.